# Separation of Concerns Practice with Repository, UoW Pattern and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I came up with a separation of concerns problem while trying to solve repository and unit of work pattern with Entity Framework Model First. In my solution I have 4 projects: Data, Domain, Repository, Console. In my data layer, I have EF, edmx file. In domain layer, I have my objects, in repository layer, i have repo interface and UOW class. In console layer, i try to write names on screen. But in order to write names on screen, I have to add EF dll to Console Project and write database connection string to app.config. But this is wrong I guess for separation of concerns. Console project should not know about EF, it should only communicate with Repo layer to use Unit of Work(UOW) class.

Here is my structure:

[image]

Two projects use EF dll which is

[image]

My simple Console app references(this is how I want it to be, only use repo layer and domian layer)

[image]

My console code is :

[image]

Here the console code doesn't work unless I add EF to project and connection string to the project. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion would help, I look into some github projects and could not find a simple solution which doesn't have connection string in `app.config` or `web.config`

Comment: The running application always supplies the connection string. For the data layer this is an injected dependency. If the DAL had the connection string you'd never be able to use it with other databases.

Comment: why would I want to use it with other databases? what do you mean?

Comment: Development, test, production, ... How would you tell the DAL which database to use when your application runs on premises at the customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string dependency is not something i see as violating the separation of concerns.
The start projects Knows the environment.
BUT:

if you want to avoid having connection strings you can create contexts passing in connection Info

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
public MyContext(DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
```

I also have EF as a package referenced so it can be loaded.

```
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

But I just checked with Resharper. It can be safe deleted.   So i dont have code references to EF. Just an environmental load/package reference.

Not breaking the code separation Domain driven development paradigm in my view